Stm32 Discovery board USB interrupt issue
I have stm32f769 discovery board and try to implement USB function (ie device mode) using ST USB stack. Intended interface is ULPI (present on board).
When I start the program, after initializing USB registers, even in situation when the board is not connected to my PC, I receive RXFLVL interrupt. Neither one of the reasons for it (5 possible PKSTS, BCNT) are set, so code exits interrupt routine with RXFLVL set, which of course provoke new entry into it.
I know I risk some negative points for not sending complete code, but it is not so short and dispersed in few files, however it is basically ST USB stack (adapted for HS and ULPI). I can only hope someone faced similar situation and have any inputs for me.
What follows is part of interrupt routine, mentioned (Keil MDK5).
  ...
  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG(hpcd, USB_OTG_GINTSTS_RXFLVL))
    {      // execution enters here no matter if the board is connected to PC or not
      USB_MASK_INTERRUPT(hpcd->Instance, USB_OTG_GINTSTS_RXFLVL);
      temp = USBx->GRXSTSP; 
      ep = &hpcd->OUT_ep[temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_EPNUM];                         
      if (((temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_PKTSTS) >> 17) ==  STS_DATA_UPDT)  //pass over
      {
        if ((temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT) != 0U)
        {
          (void)USB_ReadPacket(USBx, ep->xfer_buff,  (uint16_t)((temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT) >> 4)); 
          ep->xfer_buff += (temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT) >> 4;  
          ep->xfer_count += (temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT) >> 4;     
        }   
      }     
      else if (((temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_PKTSTS) >> 17) ==  STS_SETUP_UPDT) //pass over
      {                                         
        (void)USB_ReadPacket(USBx, (uint8_t *)hpcd->Setup, 8U);     
        ep->xfer_count += (temp & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT) >> 4;       
      }                                     
      else
      {
        /*...*/    dummy= 5;   // it enters here 
      }
      USB_UNMASK_INTERRUPT(hpcd->Instance, USB_OTG_GINTSTS_RXFLVL);
    }
  ...


  int main(void)
  {
    MPU_Config();
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    My_UART_Init();
    USBD_Init(&USBD_Device, &My_Desc, 0);
    USBD_RegisterClass(&USBD_Device, USBD_My_CLASS);  
    USBD_Start(&USBD_Device);
  
    while (1)
    {       
        for (i=0; i< 88; i++){dummy++;}
    }
  }

